# Using grep and whoami to list processes that aren't owned by the current user

Tags: command-line, grep, ps

`ps aux --sort=-%cpu | grep -v 'whoami'` command is supposed to output processes that are not started by the effective user. However, it prints out my user's processes as well as other users'. Please explain what's wrong.

Comment: it looks like you have used 'whoami`  which will result in it listing all those who aren't of username "whoami".  i think you meant `whoami` (with backticks which this site tranforms to a command) which will be replaced with the result of $USER (ie. your username) and thus will exclude your username (it won't work anyway if for example your username was just a "r" - 'root' would also be excluded as it contains the "r"..   a command within backtick is excuted & its result replaces the backslash-quoted bit..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep -v 'whoami'` excludes lines matching literal string `whoami`

If you want to exclude lines matching the output of the `whoami` command, you need to replace the single quotes with backticks

```sh
ps aux --sort=-%cpu | grep -vFe `whoami`
```

or use the `$(...)` form of command substitution instead

```sh
ps aux --sort=-%cpu | grep -vFe "$(whoami)"
```

---

Alternatively, you could skip the `grep` altogether by negating the user selection directly:

```sh
ps -Nu `whoami` --sort=-%cpu u
```

Comment: Any reason not to use the standard `$USER` variable here? Why launch a separate process?

Answer (score 3):

As [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/983956/295286) already explained, your command is wrong because it filters against *literal string* `whoami`, and you could use `grep -v "$(whoami)"`; you could also use  `grep -v "$USER"`  to achieve desired effect.

Another, better way would be to let `ps` handle filtering with `-Nu` as steeldriver showed or `top`:

```
$ top -u '!root'  -n 1
```

However, I would recommend you use actual login name - the *literal string* - as in `grep -v 'myuser'` for three reasons:

1. It is possible to create a user with `*` character:

   ```
    $ sudo -p ">" useradd  -s /bin/bash -p "$(mkpasswd -m SHA-512 '123')" 'myuser1*'
    >

    $ su 'myuser1*'
    Password: 
    myuser1*@eagle:/home/xieerqi$
   ```

   Why is this important ? Because  when you use `$()` without quoting, wildcard can become an issue with shell globbing if there exist files which may contain part of the username, then the command will break:

   ```
   myuser1*@eagle:/home/xieerqi$ ps aux | strace -e execve grep -v 
   $(whoami) > /dev/null
   execve("/bin/grep", ["grep", "-v", "myuser1.pdf", "myuser1.txt"], 
   [/* 82 vars */]) = 0
   +++ exited with 1 +++
   ```

   Notice how shell expanded `myuser1*` into `myuser1.pdf` and `myuser1.txt`, in accordance with shell globbing. Not what you expected, right ?
2. Second reason - if you're logging into multiple usernames ( which some system administrators may do) or have multiple terminals open, you can get confused by `whoami` output:

   ```
   $ whoami
   root
   $ logname
   xieerqi
   ```

   If your intent is to filter out `root` processes, this will work, but if you're logged in as `root` yet want to filter out your admin user's processes - `whoami` will give you not the thing you intended.
3. Environment variables can be unset:

   ```
   $ unset USER
   $ echo "empty $USER ?"
   empty  ?
   ```

So what  did we learn from this ?

- quote the variables !
- know what you're actually logged in as and what your intent is
- be careful with passing stuff to `grep`
- try to make use of commands and their options whenever possible

Comment: who are you????

Comment: @Smile Well, I am a human.  what do you mean ?

Comment: @Smile and who are you ? :)  Come to Ask Ubuntu chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: I went to the chatting room and not much people are chatting there.

Comment: @Smile do you have weixin ?

Comment: I don't know what weixin is. Is it another chatting program?

Comment: @Smile yep, it's a Chinese chatting app. I was guessing you might be Chinese :)