# Take user name as input: if user is logged in, display running processes belonging to the user

Tags: bash, scripts, users, process

I want to write a script that takes the name of a user as command line input. If that user is logged in then it will display the processes the user is running. If he/she is not logged in, then the script should mention this.

My attempt is not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Who are you?"
read user
echo $user
name=$(whoami)
if[$user == $name]
then
  top -u $user
else
  echo "not logged in"
fi
```

Comment: Run your script with `bash -x`, "who the user is" is already provided in the `$USER` environment variable.

Comment: You are checking whether the user is the same as the one who runs the script, not whether he is logged in. How about `top -u $user || echo "$user is not logged in"`? This would save you the whole `if` expression…

Comment: By the way: Always [quote](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) variables with input you got from a user!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `who -u` command to list the users who are logged in.
Then you could use `grep` to look for a specific user in the output,
and exit with success if found, or exit with failure otherwise.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'Enter username to check: ' user
if who -u | grep -q "^$user "; then
    top -u "$user"
else
    echo "User $user is not logged in"
fi
```

(Thanks to @dessert for shortening the `who -u | ...` part!)

Comment: @Zanna I meant to delete that line from the original script, and keep only the `read -p` I added. Thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 3):

What you're asking for can actually be done with a oneliner:

```
read -p"Who are you? " u&&((who -u|grep -q "^$u "&&top -u"$u")||echo "$u is not logged in")
```

But as you requested a script, here's the much nicer script version:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Who are you? " user && ((    # prompt for username, save as $user
who -u | grep -q "^$user "   &&       # test if user is logged in
top -u "$user"                   ) || # run top with that username
echo "$user is not logged in"   )     # error message
```

#### Explanations

- `read -p "Who are you? " user` – prompt for the username and save it as variable `user`
- `&&` – if that's successful, …
- `(…)` – start a subshell and do `…` in it – if you don't want to start a subshell you can use `{ …;}` instead, the space as well as the semicolon are mandatory
- `who -u | grep -q "^$user "` – call `who` and `grep` for the username at the beginning of the line (`^`) with a preceding space (so that `des` doesn't match `dessert`)
- `top -u "$user"` – run top with the username
- `||` – if that's *not* successful, i.e. if the user is not logged in
- `echo "$u is not logged in"` – print error message

NB: This can very well also be done with an `if` expression as shown in the other answers. I stuck to logical operators and brackets here because that's another way of doing it and I wanted to show how.

Answer (score 3):

To me it looks like you have misunderstood the task a little. I guess the script is something a sysadmin would use to check on users, so "Who are you?", and checking that the user running the script has entered their own username (which is what your script tries to do) is not what you are supposed to do!

I think [janos' answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986676/take-user-name-as-input-if-user-is-logged-in-display-running-processes-belongi/986680#986680) and [dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986676/take-user-name-as-input-if-user-is-logged-in-display-running-processes-belongi/986681#986681) do exactly what you want, and I don't have a better answer. But here are some tips to debug your script...

#### `test` aka `[`

You used `[` which is a shell builtin. You can see some information about it by running `help [`, but as that info tells you, it is a version of the `test` command, and more information can be found under `help test`. When I run your script (which I named `script`) I get these errors:

```
script: line 6: if[zanna == zanna]: command not found
script: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
script: line 7: `then'
```

you needed three spaces to separate the `if` and `[` commands from their arguments. Also, as Sergiy pointed out in a comment, [until Bash version 4.4](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/plain/NEWS), the `==` operator did not exist in `test` or `[`. Ubuntu 16.04 is using Bash 4.3. I have Bash 4.4 in 17.10.  You can correct the syntax error like this:

```
if [ "$user" = "$name" ]
```

You could also have avoided assigning an extra variable by making that test

```
if [ "$user" = "$(whoami)" ]
```

but brevity does not always yield clarity, especially in shell scripts, and besides, **this isn't what you really want to do**, because the user running the script has to be logged in to run a script, so even the syntactically correct version of your script would only be checking that the user typed their username correctly, which isn't what the task asks for.

#### `read`

`read` is a Bash builtin command. You can get information on it by running `help read`.

When you use the `read` command, you probably want to use the `-r` option to prevent any backslashes in the input from acting as escapes.

Also, rather than `echo`ing the user prompt, you can use `read`'s `-p` option and write the prompt after `-p` for a more concise script.

```
echo "Who are we checking on? "
read -r user
```

does the same as

```
read -rp "Who are we checking on? " user
```

You also don't strictly need to name the variable, since `read` puts the input into a variable `REPLY` automatically. You can test this:

```
read -rp "Who are we checking on? "
echo "$REPLY"
```

Of course, you often want to name the variable. I think `user` was a good choice for this one.

#### `if`

`if` is also a shell builtin, so you can find out about it by running `help if`. You'll see that it checks the command after it and executes the `then` branch *if the exit status of that command was zero* (ie it was successful). [janos' answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986676/take-user-name-as-input-if-user-is-logged-in-display-running-processes-belongi/986680#986680) uses `if` without `test` or `[` by simply collecting the exit status of `grep`:

```
who -u | grep -q "^$user "
```

searches the output of `who -u` to see if any line starts with the value of the `$user` variable. `^` is start of line, and the `-q` option suppresses output. `grep`'s exit status is zero if it finds a match, so if `$user` is found, the `then` branch of the `if` structure will be executed, but if `grep` fails to find anything, the `else` branch of the `if` structure will be executed (if it exists).

[dessert's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986676/take-user-name-as-input-if-user-is-logged-in-display-running-processes-belongi/986681#986681) uses only the shell's logic to define actions for success and failure of a command - even `if` is not necessary here :)

#### `test` again

Since checking exit status suffices, I don't think you need the `[` or `test` command at all. If you really want to use it, you could use something like

```
[ -n "$(w -h | grep "^$user ")" ]
```

The whole command substitution must be quoted or `[` will complain of too many arguments if there are multiple words in the output (since `$user` will be one word, we could also use `grep -o` to output only the match). `-n` is true if the string is not empty.

An alternative to `who -u` is `w -h`. I'm not sure which is more portable or reliable. I've noticed that `who` gives slightly different output in different terminal emulators, although not different enough to stop this script from working.

#### [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting)

Most of the time, you want to quote variables in scripts to prevent further expansions. The utilities you use to create users on Ubuntu will not allow you to create a username with spaces or any other characters that could cause the shell to perform an expansion, so I don't think it's strictly essential to quote the variable in this script. Still, it's possible for such usernames to exist, and it a good habit to quote variables that don't need to be unquoted.

---

For completeness, here is my version without `[` (it's essentially the same as janos'):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -rp "Who are we checking on? "
if w -h | grep -q "^$REPLY "; then
    echo "here's what "$REPLY" is doing:"
    top -u "$REPLY"
else
    echo "looks like "$REPLY" is not logged in."
fi
```

Comment: Couple things: `test` doesn't have `==` operator, that's only in `[[` or arithmetic compound command `((...))`, and arithmetic expansion `$((...))`.  Be careful with  `grep "^$user"` as this doesn't account for usernames like `jdoe` and `jdoe1`, so that may lead to flags.    Good answer, I like it.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I've found out why it worked for me - [the `==` operator was added to `test` in Bash 4.4](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/plain/NEWS) (which I have on 17.10)!

Comment: Good find !  This also means one more incompatibility between `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash`. I'm gonna have to go add that on Ubuntu wiki

Comment: Pretty much anything is valid in a username! [What characters should I use or not use in usernames on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/73084/what-characters-should-i-use-or-not-use-in-usernames-on-linux) and https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2008/08/13/on-valid-unix-usernames-and-ones-sanity

Comment: @dessert   Yep, and that's one of the reasons  it could break  commands if shell decides to ... oh, maybe do filename expansion on username ... See https://askubuntu.com/a/983961/295286

Comment: oh, alright then, edited slightly :P

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Enter Username: "
read check
_user="$(id -u -n)"
if [ "$check" = "$_user" ]
then
echo "User Logged In"
else
echo "User Not Logged In"
fi
```

This will do your work perfectly!